# syncing a shell script with kernel operations

Tags: linux, shell, embedded, busybox

For stopping activity in my embedded Linux system, I have the following shell script (interpreted by busybox):

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill usefulp_program
swapoff /home/.swapfile
umount -l /home
sleep 3 # While I can't find a way to sync, sleep
```

If I take off the `sleep` line, the script returns immediately, without waiting even for the `umount` (which is lazy, as for some reason it refuses to unmount otherwise). Do you know how can I wait for all the three operations to complete before finishing the script? Resorting to an arbitrary `sleep` does not look like a good solution.

Also, any hint on why I can not `umount` without the `-l`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `umount` with the `-f` (force) or `-n` (don't write to /etc/mtab) flags?

Comment: The `umount` requiring lazy probably means some file or directory is open; if you have `procfs` mounted, try: `ls -ld /proc/*/cwd /proc/*/fd/*| grep home` to see if any process has a current working directory inside `/home/` or files open inside `/home`.

Comment: Looking closely, need for -l seems a consequence of not waiting the process to die, since it uses /home.

Comment: You can't unmount a file system while any process has any file open under the mount point, or if a process has its current directory as the mount point or a directory under the mount point.  If, as your comment suggests, the script you are running is under `/home`, then you are on a hiding to nothing; you cannot unmount `/home` until none of its files are in use, and the file is in use while the script is running.  You will have to relocate your script off the `/home` file system.

Comment: The script is outside /home. The only process using /home is the one I am killing.

Comment: Does running `pkill` with a `-9` argument solve the problem that the process isn't dying fast enough? A `pkill` asks nicely for the program to die, but it might choose to keep running (keeping a file handle open in `/home`). The `-9` will force it to die.

Comment: @davidg: even with -9 there's still a race condition for the signal to be processed before the script terminates... :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the killed process to terminate.  As per your comment...

```
wait <pid>
```

...doesn't work!  So, could loop ala:

```
while ps -p <pid> > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

to wait for the killed process to terminate before doing the swapoff and umount.

Comment: wait seems to work only on child process, what is not the case here.

Comment: @lvella: thanks for the clarification... man page is misleading then (says "Wait  for each specified process and return its termination status.  Each n may be a process ID or a job  specification", only going on to mention child processes for when no argument was given).

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned you should and only the `-l` when the process is terminated. An option if it takes long/it just ignores you polite request to stop itself is using a different signal. The option would be `-9` to the kill/killall/pkill command to send the SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM. If you dont want to use the hammer on your first try you could do something like

```
pkill your_programm
sleep 10
pkill -9 your_programm
```

Comment: Incidentally this is what desktop linuxes do on shutdown. Also, you may want to try remounting the file system read only instead of unmounting it completely.